# Access SplObjectStorage data via Reflection

Tags: php, reflection, spl

Is it possible to access the data of `SplObjectStorage` using Reflection or some other method? When I use `print_r` on it, I can see there is a private property `$storage` with an array containing all the data, but I cannot access it using Reflection in any way. Is there some other possible solution to get the data without iterating over the collection with `foreach`?

Comment: I don't believe so ([have a look at the code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/spl/spl_observer.c#_spl_SplObjectStorage) if you want), but what's wrong with iterating?

Comment: @fab I don't want to affect the state of the object (changing iteration index, etc.). Anyway, I will use `clone` for now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to access the `$storage` property through Reflection because *it doesn't exist*.

What you see when you call `print_r` (or `var_dump`) on the class is *debug information*. This information is provided through the internal [`get_debug_info`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/spl/spl_observer.c#spl_object_storage_debug_info) handler of the class. This handler allows internal classes to display meaningful debugging information without defining actual properties.

A tangentially related issue shows with the following snippet:

```
$r = new ReflectionClass('DateTime');
var_dump($r->hasProperty("timezone"));
```

The above code will tell you that the class has no `timezone` property, even though you can access the `timezone` property on `DateTime` objects. The reason is that this property is not *declared*, it is only provided through the internal [`get_properties`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/date/php_date.c#date_object_get_properties) handler. Once again, this is a property that is not designed to be accessed directly, it only exists to a) provide meaningful debugging output and b) specify what should be serialized when the object is serialized.

In summary: Reflecting on "properties" of internal classes will usually not work out, simply because those properties often do not actually exist.